# convert Conditional Join in SQL to Linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a normally simple looking query in SQL as:

```
SELECT table1.Id, count(table2.col) AS OrderCol
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.Id = table2.Id
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table2.Id = table3.Id AND table2.condition = 3 //some integer value
GROUP BY table1.Id
ORDER BY count(table2.col) DESC
```

When `AND` clause appears inside **join**, I am not sure about how to convert this to LINQ...

How to achieve it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var answer = (from t1 in table1
             join t2 in table2 on t1.Id equals t2.Id into subData1
             from t2sub in subData1.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join t3 in table3 on new { Id = t2sub == null ? 0 : t2sub.Id, condition = t2sub == null ? 0 : t2sub.condition } equals new { t3.Id, condition = 3 } into subData
             from t3sub in subData.DefaultIfEmpty()
             group new { t1, t2sub } by t1.Id into subGroup
             orderby subGroup.Count(x => x.t2sub != null) descending 
             select new {
                 Id = subGroup.Key,
                 OrderCol = subGroup.Count(x => x.t2sub != null)
             }).ToList();
```

Comment: Need to correct at line `{ t2.Id, t2.condition }`... it should be `{ t2sub.Id, t2sub.condition }`

Comment: @Vikrant, fixed

Comment: still `object reference not set to an instance of an object` error comes

Comment: @Vikrant, and what now?

Answer (score 1):

It goes something like:

```
from t1 in db.Table1
join t2 in db.Table2 on t1.field equals t2.field
select new { t1.field2, t2.field3}
```